# Need to implement full fledged Multiple User Account in JB Android

Tags: android, account

I want to build a full fledged Multiple User Account in JB Android. I know it can be done using Lollipop but I want it on existing system of JB.

1) What all level of changes do I need to make?
2) UserManager class is present in JB , I think I need to make changes in it? apart from framework , Where all I need to make changes?

Answer (score 1):

Multi User accounts are not available for mobile phones under Lollipop SDK.

For mobile devices you'll need super user root access and then create a new user as you do with Linux:

```
pm create-user test
```

So... if you want to create an app that does that, make it root available and then, create the new users as regular with Linux command. ("test" will be the name of the new account in my example).

Here you have a post with the manual work: http://www.phonearena.com/news/How-to-enable-multiple-user-accounts-on-a-Jelly-Bean-device-right-now_id33001

Comment: Miki, Your Statement  "Multi User accounts are not available for mobile phones under Lollipop SDK" are you sure on this? I have seen mobile phones having Multi user Accounts on Lollipop where as not on JB. Basically I wanted to know what changes have Google done in android Lollipop from multi user account point to get this support.

Comment: Only mobile phones have Multi Users accounts on Lollipop... I'm assuming that memory management has something to do with a better control of users (each users have a partition of the internal memory). "Multi Users" exist since like... don't know... forever on Linux... and Android have a Linux kernel running.

All the management that Android has to do with Multi Users (change the entire partition in seconds, changing installed apps, backgrounds, settings, etc ) I'm sure they took a lot of perfection time to make it User Friendly.

Comment: After some research I found that , Google restricted the user to 1 before lollipop. If we need to modify it we need to make changes in framework as well as some mk files.